# How to automate screen recording ideally just on user input (keyboard/mouse)

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, screenshot, recording

Windows 7.

So at work it gets busy. Really busy. And this results in mistakes being made.

For example, someone might ring in a really long and complicated transaction. And then the customer might say "oh actually I was promised a discount on the Coax cable at 15% for quantity" resulting in the member of staff having to edit the complicated transaction. We find in so doing sometimes a line might get knocked off the bill, meaning the customer walks away without paying for that item without knowing about it.

Another example: at the end of the day we might be $103 up on cash. This is likely because a sale for $103 has been rung in the till but not finalised. Someone else has appeared and cleared the sale, in a busy moment, without meaning to.

If I could retrieve that lost sale I could book all the items out of stock so that our stock figures don't get messed up every time that happens.

I am looking for a way to record the screen of our till to file. But because I'd rather not have MASSIVE files stored on the hard disk, or indeed constant recording to the hard disk which will cause them to fail prematurely, I'd like the recording (or screen grabbing) to only occur when the screen changes, i.e. due to user input.

To further complicate matters I'd like this to happen on startup, without fanfare, so I don't need to remember to set it rolling every morning and so that popups from the program etc don't get in the way of the till software.

Any ideas?! Am I asking too much? :-)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to record what the screen looks like, any old screen recorder will do.

Ex of screen recorders:

- [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)
- [DxTory](http://exkode.com/dxtory-features-en.html)
- Shadow Play *(Nvidia GPU only)*

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain the "how" part of the question. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution (not just a random Google hit). Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.